# What is the difference between headless, service and user Kerberos keytabs

Tags: security, kerberos, hadoop

I often work on Kerberised Hadoop clusters, and have to use a variety of keytabs, such as:

- `hbase.headless.keytab`
- `hbase.service.keytab`
- `devuser.keytab`

  I'm not entirely clear on exactly what the purpose of each is, and it's not really documented online. Could anyone explain what the difference is between `headless`, `service` and `user` keytabs?

Comment: You could start by using `klist -k -t devuser.keytab` to see which account's credentials are within each file.

Comment: I'm asking more generally about the three different types, rather than diagnosing properties of specific keytabs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my understanding,
   hbase.headless.keytab = Will never expire,
   hbase.service.keytab  = valid for certain time period,
   devuser.keytab        = valid for only 24 hours.

Let me know if you found better answer .

Answer (score 0):

Headless keytab

What you call 'headless keytab' is user principal keys. This already makes an assumption that you have a user principal that corresponds to certain POSIX user it will start services without prompting for password e.g(smokeuser,hdfs,hbase). Headless principals are not bound to a specific host or node, they have the syntax: - @ EXAMPLE.COM

For Example: Headless: hdfs-mycluster@EXAMPLE.COM